# System.AccessViolationException when handing an array over to a dynamically loaded c++ DLL in C#

Tags: c#, c++, arrays, dll, pinvoke

I am dynamically loading a DLL originally written in C++ in a C# program and hand over an array as an argument like this:

```
// That's only for being able to load the DLL dynamically during runtime
[DllImport(@"C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "LoadLibrary")]
public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)] string dllToLoad);

[DllImport(@"C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);

[DllImport(@"C:\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll", EntryPoint = "FreeLibrary")]
public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

// Delegate with function signature for the DISCON function
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]
delegate void DisconDelegate(float[] arr);

static void Main(string[] args){
   // Load DLL
   IntPtr _dllhandle = IntPtr.Zero;
   DisconDelegate _discon = null;
   string dllPath = @"D:\myProject\Trivial_discon.dll";

    _dllhandle = LoadLibrary(dllPath);
    var discon_handle = GetProcAddress(_dllhandle, "DISCON");
   _discon = (DisconDelegate)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(discon_handle, typeof(DisconDelegate));

   // create the array and change it after its initialization
   float[] arr = new float[] { 5, 6, 7 };
   arr[0] = 7;

   _discon(arr);
}
```

Note that I change after the initialization once again with `arr[0] = 7;` an entry of the array. This returns the following error: System.AccessViolationException
  HResult=0x80004003
  Message=Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
  Source=
  StackTrace:

However, if I leave `arr[0] = 7;` away, it works.

So I am wondering: Why is it problematic to change an entry of the array after the initialization in this context? And how can I fix this problem, i.e., how to change the entries of an array after its initialization and still being able to hand it over as an argument to the DLL?

Comment: See the pinvoke samples : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.LoadLibrary.  You are missing a Marshal in the LoadLibrary.

Comment: @jdweng: I added the Marshal as in the example, however this did not resolve the problem yet. However, thank you for your comment!

Comment: What is the value of_discon_handle?  Either Handle is not valid or you need to run the c# AS ADMIN.  To run as ADMIN create shortcut to VS.  Then right click shortcut and select RUN  AS ADMIN.

Comment: In c# a string is a class where each character is one or two bytes.  In c language a string is a byte[] that is terminated with '\0'.  So using MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr) converts the c# string to a c language string.

Comment: GetProcAddress need to be ANSI.  See : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.GetProcAddress

Comment: GetProcAddress need to be ANSI.  See : http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.GetProcAddress.  It is really returning a byte[] string and I guess the ANSI is allowing the c# library to convert to a string.  Verify the string to make sure it looks right.  It should match the process name in Task Manager.

Comment: @jdweng: Making GetProcAddress and the MarshalAs seem to be reasonable, so I edited the code above accordingly. I also tried running the code as admin. However these measures did not resolve the problem. The _discon_handle is not zero (it is 0x00007ffb1eadce80 to be precise).

Comment: @jdweng: I think it has more to do with how arrays are handled in C++ and C#, than with loading DLL itself, since if I leave `arr[0] = 7;`, the code runs without throwing an exception.

Comment: It's not possible to help until we can see a definition of the unmanaged function. It looks to me as though it might be a wind turbine controller function as implemented in a FAST controller DLL. If so then the signature is surely wrong.

Comment: @David Heffernan: Yes, it looks like that, but its only a test Dll which adds `arr[0]` and `arr[1]` and sets `arr[2]` to the sum. The function head is `void __declspec(dllexport) __cdecl DISCON(float *arr)`, but I don't have access to the implementation. I just created a function with the same head, which should do the same (i.e. `arr[3] = arr[1] + arr[2]; `). With my own function, the problem vanished, so there must happen something else within the DLL which causes the problem. So handing over the array does not seem to be the problem. I'll check that out. Thank you for your helpful comments!

Comment: The DISCON function has four arguments if I recall correctly. Also, what is your return attribute trying to achieve? I expect it will be ignored because the function is declared with void return. But still....

Answer (score -2):

You need to convert the array from managed memory to unmanaged memory.  Try following

```
       static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Data data = new Data();
            data.arr = new float[] { 5, 6, 7 };
            IntPtr arrPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(data.arr.Length * sizeof(float));
            Marshal.StructureToPtr(data, arrPtr, true);
        }
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct Data
        {

            public float[] arr;
        }
```

Comment: This does not seem to be the solution yet, since I am getting now the exception `System.AccessViolationException` in the line with `Marshal.StructureToPtr(data, arrPtr, true);` instead of  in the line with the DLL call `_discon(arrPtr)` (which is the subsequent one).

Comment: Are you using lasted posted code?  I did an update on the code and tested what is now posted and do not get an exception.

Comment: I tested your code once again. It seems that if I run it once after I opened Visual Studio, it works. If I  run it a second time, I get again the the exception `System.AccessViolationException: 'Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.'` It throws this exception in further runs as well.

Comment: I suspect something is wrong with the return value since it runs once.  The function doesn't return anything so why do you have : [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)]  A IntPtr is 4 bytes which looks good.  Do the function return a value?

Comment: This strange behavior even occurs if `_discon(arr);` is commented out. 
The function does not return any value, but it changes the values of `arr`, which shall be used as "output".

Comment: The is some sort of alignment issue.  The pointer is return unmanaged memory.  And the size is correct if the c++ is using a float (not double).  So now I'm suspecting the Project properties.  I would use X86 option.  If the c++ was compiled as x64 then the code is grabbing 8 bytes at a time.  If it doesn't need all 8 it still address all 8 at a time.  If the c# is only using 32 bits the c++ could be reading past the end of the memory assigned by c#.   Try changing From : DisconDelegate(float[] arr) To : DisconDelegate(IntPtr arr)

Comment: I use a x64 compiled DLL, and I am using a x64 compiler for C# as well. I tested now also using a loop for assigning values to the array like `for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){ arr[i] = i; }`, which works well without exception. Again, if place the line `arr[0]=1;`, I get the `System.AccessViolationException`. @jdweng: I really appreciate your persistent help!

Comment: In c++ the float[] array would be 12 (3 * 4) consecutive bytes.  To make it easy to debug I would first try a UInt32 (also 32 bytes) to see if the 12 bytes are properly being passed.  Floating point is harder to tell if the data is correct.  I would send fixed data like new UInt32[] {0x1234, 0x5678, 0x9ABC};